# Open php file and put selected data in input and save

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've looking around how to open a file but open and put a selected row in inputbox (like loading the current as IPB forums has) and save after.

Basically this screenshot is the inputbox's that i wanna load the data from the config file (its not a config.ini its a php file and i wanna open the array information and load it to input and after i be able to just save it).
[where i wanna load the info to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNMSo.png)

Here is my config example:

```
$config['emailserver'] = array(
  'recv'  => 'asgasg',  
  'host'  => 'smtp.gmail.com',      
  'user'  => 'gasgasg',  
  'pass'  => 'asgasg',    
);
```

Currently using Codeigniter 3.0 framework

Comment: Putting the data into the inputs is trivial. But this isn't a code writing service. Please show us what you have tried and where it has, or has not, worked as expected. You might find Codeigniters [Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) to be very useful.

Comment: You will probably find saving to config files a lot more difficult than other options i.e. a database.

Comment: Alright i've figured it out, by putting value attribute in inputs with an echo of the array that i wanna edit (the config) and basicly i just save this new inputs on config (by using form validation and set rules from new input) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from your controller/view:

```
$emailServer = ( array ) $this->config->item( 'emailserver' );
```

More about the [Codeigniter Config Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html)

Comment: Seriously, it's not clear that you know that you can use any number of individual config files and load them on demand. But anyway...

Comment: This is +/- what i had used but it helps for whos searching to use config array in Codeigniter. Thanks anyway for remminder